# How to remove particular character and spcl character from API response - Javascript

Tags: javascript, typescript

Could some one tell me, how to get expected output for below combination of data.

I'm having API response with properties like `someData: 'test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]'`.

Here i want to remove whatever coming like this for few scenarios.

**Actual:**

`someData: 'test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]' // applicable for few scenarios`.

**expected:**

`someData: ''`

it tried like below, but getting as its again.

```
var sample= "test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]";
var removed= str.replace('/test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]','');
console.log(removed);
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You are using `replace` function on `str` variable. Instead, you should use `sample` variable. And remove `/` from the beginning of the search string.

```
var sample = "test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]";
var removed = sample.replace('test data [sampleA:a][sampleB:b]','');
console.log(removed);
```

Comment: Ha. Great. Let me try and come back